# $\lim_{n\to\infty}ne^{\frac{x}{n}}-n = x$?

Tags: limits

Im fairly sure it's $x$. Here's what I've got so far.
$\lim_{n\to\infty}ne^{\frac{x}{n}}-n = \lim_{n\to\infty}n(e^{\frac{x}{n}}-1) = \lim_{n\to\infty}n(-1+\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i!n^i}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}x+\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i!n^{i-1}}$

Comment: It is possible to develop an entire theory of exponential and logarithmic functions starting from the definition $\log x=\lim_{n\to \infty} n(x^{1/n}-1)$. The result in your question is an immediate application of this well known limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have :

$$ne^{\frac{x}{n}}-n=n\left(1+\frac{x}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)-n=x+o(1) $$

So you get :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}ne^{\frac{x}{n}}-n = x $$

Comment: Seems a bit off... That $o(1)$ term has nothing forcing it towards a specific limit, so how does it vanish?

Comment: $o(1)$ means that the term is negligible compared to 1, so it's a function that goes to $0$ when $n$ goes to infinity. For example, $f=o(g) $, then $\lim f/g =0$, if you replace $g$ by $1$, you get that the small $o$ goes to 0

Comment: That's weird, I guess my understanding that $o(1)$ is a term upper bounded by $1$ is incorrect.  If this is proper terminology then no worries.

Comment: By the conventions I know of, the upper bound by 1 is denoted by a big $o$ , and it would be $O(1)$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.